# MEF like framework for angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, mef

We have built a web application using asp.net MVC 5 with AngularJS. This means most (all except one) of the views are html files and controllers are .js files. All calls to the backend are ajax calls (web api).

Now, we have decided that our application should be 'extendable'. This poses no problem for the backend code since we can use MEF for that. But how should I approach this problem when I want to display different views when some plugin is intalled? How do I inject the .js controller files with new pieces of code? Is it even possible to do such a thing?